# Using For loops to find and display specific elements in one of the arrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to use a for loop to find and display certain players in each list, how would I use a for loop to find "Nia Reed", while assuming you don't know which sport Nia plays. Any and all help appreciated.

Ive tried doing this to display Kat Asman from SoccerNames, but Im unsure how to do this without using SoccerNames.

```
ArrayList<String> nList = new ArrayList<String>();
     String findString = "Kat Asman";

    for(String s: SoccerNames){
        if(s.contains(findString)){
            nList.add(s);
        }
        System.out.println(nList);
    }
```

This is the full program

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArraysPrep
{

ArrayList<String> FootballNames;
ArrayList<String> VolleyballNames;
ArrayList<String> SoccerNames;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bigArray;

public ArraysPrep()
{
    FootballNames = new ArrayList<>();
    VolleyballNames = new ArrayList<>();
    SoccerNames = new ArrayList<>();
    bigArray = new ArrayList<>();

    fillInNames();
    fillInBigTable();
}

private void fillInNames()
{
    FootballNames.add("Marcus Allen");
    FootballNames.add("Kyle Alston");
    FootballNames.add("Troy Apke");
    FootballNames.add("Matthew Baney");
    FootballNames.add("Saquon Barkley");

    VolleyballNames.add("Kendall White");
    VolleyballNames.add("Kaitlyn Hord");
    VolleyballNames.add("Bryanna Weiskircher");
    VolleyballNames.add("Nia Reed");
    VolleyballNames.add("Serena Gray");
    VolleyballNames.add("Alli Frantti");

    SoccerNames.add("Amanda Dennis");
    SoccerNames.add("Emily Ogle");
    SoccerNames.add("Ellie Jean");
    SoccerNames.add("Kat Asman");
    SoccerNames.add("Laura Suero");

/** for (String s: SoccerNames){
System.out.println(s);
}
*/

ArrayList<String> nList = new ArrayList<String>();
     String findString = "Kat Asman";

    for(String s: SoccerNames){
        if(s.contains(findString)){
            nList.add(s);
        }
        System.out.println(nList);
    }
}

private void fillInBigTable()
{
    bigArray.add(SoccerNames);
    bigArray.add(VolleyballNames);
    bigArray.add(FootballNames);


}


}



''''''''
public class app
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArraysPrep ap = new ArraysPrep();
}

}
```

Comment: Im not sure how to display "Kat Asman" without using SccerNames.

Comment: What do you mean without using Soccernames? You could just iterate over all of the list if there is no indicator what Sport the Person is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really think you need to loop through the whole array list to find whether an element is contained in it.

This:

```
for(String s: SoccerNames) {
    if(s.contains(findString)) {
        nList.add(s);
    }
}
```

Could be replaced with this:

```
if(nList.contains(findString)) {
    nList.add(s);
}
```

Then, you can loop through `bigArray` and do something similar for each of the array lists in order to display a certain name.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition, I think you should use the class with several fields for your sportsmen.

It could be something like this:

```
public class Athlete {

private String name;
private Sport sport;

public Athlete(String name, Sport sport) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sport = sport;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Sport getSport() {
    return sport;
}
```

}

Or to create several implementations of Athete interface, like:

```
Volleyballist extends Atlete // or implements
```

So you could use only one ArrayList and store there all of your athletes and search in it.

Answer (score 0):

In the way you're approaching the problem, I think the best solution is making a list picking the values of the 3 others to it and then, searching with for.

```
private void lookingFor(String player){
    ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
    all.addAll(SoccerNames);
    all.addAll(FootballNames);
    all.addAll(VolleyballNames);

    for(String a : all) {
        if(player == a) {
            bigList.add(a);
            break;
        }
    }


    }
```

I didn't tested it. But I think you should create a class of players, with its name, an id and the sport he plays, and pick with this atribute instead. In that way, you can even make a single list instead of four.

```
public class Player {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String sport;

    public Player() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Player(Integer id, String name, String sport) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.sport = sport;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSport() {
        return sport;
    }

    public void setSport(String sport) {
        this.sport = sport;
    }


}
```

And then:

```
ArrayList<Player> players;
ArrayList<Player> bigList;

private void filterPlayer(String name){
for(Player p : players){
if(p.getName() == name){
bigList.add(p);
break;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use lists. Use sets - these don't allow repetition, and I'm certain you don't need a possibility to have a player in same list twice (I bet this makes no sense in your domain).

Set has method `contains` which would tell you if element is contained within the set or not right away - without any loops whatsoever.

Then if you want to be able to tell in which of the sets the player is contained (e.g. whether he was in Soccer, Football or Volleyball) without iterating over that specific sport - you could put those sets in a `Map` where a `String` with sport name would be the key, and `Set<String>` would be a value.

And yes, don't give local variables of fields names starting with uppercase character - that's against Java code conventions.

Example code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    Map<String, Set<String>> sportsToPlayers = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public void populatePlayers() {
        Set<String> footballPlayers = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<String> volleyballPlayers = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<String> soccerPlayers = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        footballPlayers.add("Marcus Allen");
        footballPlayers.add("Kyle Alston");
        footballPlayers.add("Troy Apke");
        footballPlayers.add("Matthew Baney");
        footballPlayers.add("Saquon Barkley");

        volleyballPlayers.add("Kendall White");
        volleyballPlayers.add("Kaitlyn Hord");
        volleyballPlayers.add("Bryanna Weiskircher");
        volleyballPlayers.add("Nia Reed");
        volleyballPlayers.add("Serena Gray");
        volleyballPlayers.add("Alli Frantti");
        // Added to test for multiple sports for 1 player
        volleyballPlayers.add("Kat Asman");

        soccerPlayers.add("Amanda Dennis");
        soccerPlayers.add("Emily Ogle");
        soccerPlayers.add("Ellie Jean");
        soccerPlayers.add("Kat Asman");
        soccerPlayers.add("Laura Suero");

        sportsToPlayers.put("Football", footballPlayers);
        sportsToPlayers.put("Volleyball", volleyballPlayers);
        sportsToPlayers.put("Soccer", soccerPlayers);
    }

    private Set<String> findPlayerSports(String playerName) {
        Set<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> sportsToPlayersEntry : sportsToPlayers.entrySet()) {
            String sportName = sportsToPlayersEntry.getKey();
            Set<String> playerNames = sportsToPlayersEntry.getValue();
            if (playerNames.contains(playerName)) {
                result.add(sportName);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String findPlayerSport(String playerName) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> sportsToPlayersEntry : sportsToPlayers.entrySet()) {
            String sportName = sportsToPlayersEntry.getKey();
            Set<String> playerNames = sportsToPlayersEntry.getValue();
            if (playerNames.contains(playerName)) {
                return sportName;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Test() {
        populatePlayers();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        // Find all sports for player
        System.out.println(test.findPlayerSports("Kat Asman"));

        // Find one sport for player
        System.out.println(test.findPlayerSport("Kat Asman"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<String> nList = new ArrayList<String>();
     String findString = "Kat Asman";
     List<String> lst = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(SoccerNames));
     lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(FootballNames));
     lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(VolleyballNames));

    for(String s: lst){
        if(s.contains(findString)){
            nList.add(s);
        }
        System.out.println(nList);
    }
```

You can use a method of [**Merging more than One arrays into a single array/list**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/arrays_merge.htm), so that you can **iterate** through all the three arrays in just **one loop**.

**Hope that works.**

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried executing this in my program, however I got an error for these two lines -----------  lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(FootballNames));
     lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(VolleyballNames));                                                                     The Collection.addAll is not applicable because it has incompatible bounds, The lower bound is: ArrayList<String>, and the Upper bound is: String, Object. Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: System.arraycopy(<array_which_you_want_to_copy-target_array>, 0, <destination_array>, 0, <length_of_target_array>);

Comment: @D.Cannon try it